# Реализация push_back для вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Мне  нужно написать реализацию `push_back` для вектора. Но я не  знаю как правильно.

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(const T& value)
{
    int* result = new int[mSize];

    for (decltype(mSize) i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
    {
        if (i != mSize - 1)
        {
            result[i] = mVector[i];
        }
        else
        {
            result[i] = value;
            break;
        }
    }

    mVector = result;
}
```

У меня есть  3  переменные

```
 private:
     size_t mSize;
     size_t mCapacity;
     T* mVector;
```

Переделала:

```
template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::PushBack(const T& value)
{
    if (mSize == mCapacity)
    {
        size_t capacity = mCapacity * 2;
        // Выделить новый массив tmp размером mCapacity*2
        T* result = new T[capacity];

        // Перенести в него всю информацию из старого массива
        for (decltype(mSize) i = 0; i < mSize; ++i)
            result[i] = mVector[i];

        // Удалить старый и присвоить новый ( delete[] mVector; mVector = tmp)
        delete[] mVector;
        mVector = result
                  // Не забыть обновить mCapacity = mCapacity*2
                  mCapacity = capacity;
    }

    mVector[mSize++] = value;
}
```

Comment: В вашей текущей реализации утекает mVector. Ещё когда вы вычтите  mSize - 1, если mSize = 0, то выражение станет очень большим. А так логика у вас правильная.

Comment: Не понял. У вас `push_back(const T& value)` и массив `T* mVector;`. Почему вы тогда выделяете массив `int`???  Откуда взялся `int`?

Answer (score 4):

Набросок:

```
if (mSize == mCapacity)
{
    // Выделить новый массив tmp размером mCapacity*2
    // Перенести в него всю информацию из старого массива
    // Удалить старый и присвоить новый ( delete[] mVector; mVector = tmp)
    // Не забыть обновить mCapacity = mCapacity*2
}
mVector[mSize++] = value;
```

Примерно так.

Comment: mVector[mSize++] = value; а как можно  переписать : [mSize++] ??? а то я не совсем понимаю как оно работает. увеличивается но как?

Comment: Это выражение сначала сохраняет в элементе mVector[mSize], а потом увеличивает mSize на единицу. То же, что и `mVector[mSize] = value; mSize = mSize + 1;`